# Thermal receipt printer printing blank space after the content in receipt

Tags: printing, thermal-printer, epson, bixolon-printer

I am printing a receipt using `window.print();` but a receipt containing unnecessary space on the page.
I am using a printer (STAR TSP100 CUTTER, BIXOLON, and EPSON T88V)

Sample of receipt.

[image]

Comment: The printer name specified in the tag and the printer name written in the question text are different. Which is correct? Also, are the printer, device driver, and print settings consistent? And what is the OS? For example, if you have a STAR printer, why not read this article and change the paper settings? [How do I adjust my receipt printer margins on my Windows PC?](https://support.mindbodyonline.com/s/article/203254923-How-do-I-adjust-my-receipt-printer-margins-on-my-Windows-PC?language=en_US)

Comment: Hi @kunif, Basically I have tried on both printers, the issue is the same. and also I have tried the setting mentioned in the link that you provided but unfortunately, that's also not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the printer then properties uncheck print page number at the bottom. Your paper settings most likely are 80mmx some big number hence the long paper and since you have print page number it feeds till the end of the paper